# Link to JUnit 3 Tutorial in JUnit tag-wiki seems to be broken

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I noticed that the link to [JUnit 3 Tutorial](http://pub.admc.com/howtos/junit3x/junit3x.html) in
the [JUnit Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/junit/info) seems to be broken.

[image]

I decided to post it on meta so that someone could edit the tag-wiki and insert an updated link to a JUnit 3 doc/API.

Comment: And that someone is you!  Congratulations!

Comment: Ok, I did. As it was my first tag-wiki edit, I was a bit reluctant. :)

Comment: Can you change "Using Junit In Eclipse" to "Using JUnit In Eclipse" too? You can edit your pending edit.

Comment: @approxiblue. Done. I think Using `JUnit in Eclipse` is better. Edited it that way.